# Post to a Url with a Querystring in Ruby

Tags: ruby, net-http

In Ruby, it doesn't appear that it's possible to POST to a URL that has a querystring using Net:HTTP.  At least, in my tests it gets dropped, and there's a 3 year old discussion [here](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/168426) about how it doesn't work.

So, what's a decent way to go about it?  I'd rather not add a dependency on Mechanize or similar, if there's a simpler way to do it.  And, given that it should be possible to be compliant with the specs, and today is 3 years later, I'm hoping something has changed.

Comment: FWIW, cURL handles this perfectly, as does the WebRequest class in .NET.

Comment: Did you workaround this?

Answer (score 0):

rest-client is a small wrapper over Net::HTTP: https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client

```
RestClient.post('http://example.com/resource', {
  :param1 => 'one', 
  :nested => {:param2 => 'two'},
})
```

Comment: Those are all post params.  What I'm looking to post to is 'http://example.com/resource?foo=bar' *plus* post params.  Seems like RestClient is dropping 'foo=bar' just like Net::HTTP does.

Comment: @Tome: I see, you want query + post. Then rest-client, being a wrapper, is not useful.

Answer (score -1):

it should work. Try this:

```
RestClient.post 'http://example.com/resource?foo=bar', {:param1 => 'one'}
```

with the RestClient gem specified above. You'll see: 'bar', in the params[:foo]